# dscl create user doesn't work on el capitan

Tags: macos, root, osx-elcapitan, superuser, dscl

I am trying to create user on OS X El Capitan with admin priviliges from super-user mode.
After running `/sbin/fsck -fy` and `/sbin/mount -uw /` and `launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.opendirectoryd.plist` everything works. But after `dscl . -create/Users/USERNAME` i got error no such file or directory. I tried it even with SIP disabled but it doesn't work too. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply, but SIP had no effect.

I finally solved it. The problem was `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.DirectoryServices.plist` that was used in 10.6 and earlier, I was using `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.opendirectoryd.plist`
The `dscl` commands were executed despite the error with plist and user got created.

Answer (score 0):

In El Capitan, the mounts have been changed so that
not even root can edit files in some mounts...ACL changes.

The feature is called SIP and is explained in other
stack exchange posts:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11

essentially, can boot into recovery mode, type csrutil disable,
boot back into default user mode, make changes,
then presumably, you might want to re-enable csrutil similarly.